# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression

Tags: c#

I try to run this code fragment.

But I can this error:

```
$exception  {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression'."}  System.InvalidCastException
```

on this line:

```
  fields.Add(((MemberExpression)ue.Operand).Member.Name.ToLower());
```

```
 class Program
    {

        public static string CreateUrl(string url, params Expression<Func<User, object>>[] fieldSelectors)
        {
            var fields = new List<string>();

            foreach (var selector in fieldSelectors)
            {
                var body = selector.Body;
                if (body is MemberExpression me)
                {
                    fields.Add(me.Member.Name.ToLower());
                }
                else if (body is UnaryExpression ue)
                {
                    fields.Add(((MemberExpression)ue.Operand).Member.Name.ToLower());
                }

            }


            var selectedFields = string.Join(',', fields);

            return string.Concat(url, "?fields=", selectedFields);

        }

        public static string CreateUrl(string url, params string[] fields)
        {

            var selectedFields = string.Join(',', fields);
            return string.Concat(url, "?fields=", selectedFields);
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            string url = "http://www.exmaple.com/users";

            CreateUrl(url, url => url.Name, url => 1).Dump("1");

             CreateUrl(url, "Name", "age").Dump("2");         

            Console.ReadKey();


        }
    }


    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

So what I have to correct?

Thank you

Comment: You are casting `ue.Operand` to `MemberExpression` while it is not. You need to handle all possible/supported expressions here. In this case -  `ConstantExpression` (i.e. `url => 1`).

Comment: What exactly do you mean with this: ou need to handle all possible/supported expressions here?

Comment: It means that you need to do something similar to what you do with `body` - check expression type (with `if(.. is ..)` or `switch` or some other way) and act accordingly. I don't know what the logic is - so what should be added to the `fields` param of query  if ` url => 1` is passed but if it is a viable scenario you need to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my... I had a typo:

This is the correct way to do it:

```
CreateUrl(url, u => u.Name, u => u.Age).Dump("1");
CreateUrl(url, "Name", "Age").Dump("2");
```

Answer (score 0):

When I glance at their class definitions, I don't see any direct relation enabling you being able to do the cast.

[`public class MemberExpression : System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.memberexpression?view=net-5.0)

[`public sealed class UnaryExpression : System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.unaryexpression?view=net-5.0)

Comment: It does look as answer on question "why" rather then "what I have to correct?" which OP has.

Comment: @GuruStron so what?

Comment: So it looks to me more like comment to the OP's question, not an answer, so I added a comment that marks that I think your answer could be improved.